# Super low accuracy for neural network model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, cross-validation

I followed a tutorial on neural network model evaluation using cross-validation with code:

```
# Multiclass Classification with the Iris Flowers Dataset 
import numpy 
import pandas 
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense 
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier 
from keras.utils import np_utils 
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score 
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
# fix random seed for reproducibility 
seed = 7 
numpy.random.seed(seed) 
# load dataset 
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/iris.data", header=None) 
dataset = dataframe.values 
X = dataset[:,0:4].astype(float) 
Y = dataset[:,4] 

# encode class values as integers 
encoder = LabelEncoder() 
encoder.fit(Y) 
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y) 

# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded) 
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y) 

# define baseline model 
def baseline_model():

# create model
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=4, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="normal"))
  model.add(Dense(3, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="normal"))

# Compile model
  model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer= 'adam' , metrics=[ 'accuracy' ])

  return model 
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0) 
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed) 
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold) 
print("Accuracy: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

The accuracy was supposed to be around `95.33% (4.27%)` but I got `~Accuracy: 34.00% (13.15%)` on a few attempts. The model code seems exactly the same. I downloaded the data from [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data) as instructed. What could go wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=4, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="normal"))
```

With this:

```
model.add(Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
```

Then, your output layer as:

```
model.add(Dense(3, activation="softmax", kernel_initializer="normal"))
```

Your hidden layers were *minuscule*, and your activation function was wrong. For 3+ classes, it must be `softmax`.

**FULL** working code:

```
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

X, encoded_Y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
mms = MinMaxScaler()
X = mms.fit_transform(X)

dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

def baseline_model():

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=4, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="normal"))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="normal"))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation="softmax", kernel_initializer="normal"))

    model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer='adam', metrics=[
        'accuracy' ])

    return model

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=200, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
print(results)
```

```
Out[5]: 
array([0.60000002, 0.93333334, 1.        , 0.66666669, 0.80000001,
       1.        , 1.        , 0.93333334, 0.80000001, 0.86666667])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It slightly improved to `36.67% (15.28%)` but unfortunately still quite low..

Comment: try CNN before dense.

Comment: @NicolasGervais thank you. I got the same results. What I am not sure is 2 out of the 10 outputs are around 60%. Does that mean 2/10 trials have low accuracy which indicates that model performance might not be stable? How is it possible that the tutorial managed to achieve `95.33%`?

Comment: The performance is somewhat unstable because it's a tiny dataset, with very few variables. Your dataset is even smaller when you do the "folds". Admittedly, I didn't play with hyperparameters much. I just wanted to make it work. You might want to decrease the optimizer's learning rate so it doesn't dangle around the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the chance alone, you should get 33% accuracy.

How you can improve your code:

1. Normalise the data.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

2. Increase the number of neurons in the layer,
3. Change output's activation function from `sigmoid` do `softmax`,
4. Use `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss for the output,

```
# define baseline model 
def baseline_model():

# create model
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(3, activation="softmax"))

# Compile model
  model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer= 'adam' , metrics=[ 'accuracy' ])

  return model
```

5. Change `nb_epoch` (old Keras) to `epochs`,

```
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=50, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
```

This way you'll have around 90% accuracy. If you run it for more than 50 epochs, you'll eventually overfit your model and you can even reach 100% accuracy, but the model won't generalise well.

Remember, that fully-connected layers are not always the best solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask what if we use test data to evaluate accuracy? Will it still overfit? Replacing the code you advised while keeping the rest constant I got 92% acc